# initramfs on zram

Tags: initramfs, zram

I use a minimal initramfs as my root filesystem which I load from the network. Since the initramfs is just there to get the system started (and I have no other rootfs) I'd like it to take up as little memory as possible. From what I understand the initramfs loads into /dev/ram0.

Is it possible to load initramfs into /dev/zram0?